# SQL Force Left Join to Print No Match

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with a query. I have a bunch of cars, and there are types of cars. For each type, a user can select one car, and I'm saving this in the database. When I want to retrieve the data I run into trouble:

```
[
  {
    "id_typecar": 1,
    "nom_typecar": "Type17",
    "id_car": 14,
    "id_user": 3,
    "cars": [
      {
        "id_car": 1,
        "nom_car": "775",
        }
      },
      {
        "id_car": 2,
        "nom_car": "048",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
 //Not displayed if user_id != 1 or null -> I want to display that
    "id_typecar": 2,
    "nom_typecar": "Type1",
    "id_car": 13,
    "id_user": 1, //expected output "id_user": null
    "cars": [
      {
        "id_car": 11,
        "nom_car": "123",
      },
      {
        "id_car": 12,
        "nom_car": "456,
      },
      {
        "id_car": 17,
        "nom_car": "789",
      }
]
```

And my query :

```
    return TypeCars::with('cars')
        ->leftJoin('cars_user', 'cars_user.id', '=', 'type_cars.id')
        ->where('cars_user.id' = 1)
        ->orWhereNull('cars_user.id')
        ->get()
        ->toJson();
```

I wanted to retrieve the data even if the id_user is not there yet because I must display types and cars. I added the leftJoin constraint with a `where "null" or where cars_user.userid = ?` but if user 3 chose one type of car that user 1 has not chosen (because it won't null or userid = 1), it would not display cars anymore.

Thank you!

**EDIT :**

Actual output :

```
+---------------------------------+
| id_typecar name_typecar id_user |
+---------------------------------+
| 1 Type1Car 14                   |
| 2 Type2Car 13                   |
| 2 Type2Car 13                   |
| 3 Type3Car NULL                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Expected output :

```
+---------------------------------+
| id_typecar name_typecar id_user |
+---------------------------------+
| 1 Type1Car 14                   |
| 1 Type1Car NULL                 | <-- needed for the display
| 2 Type2Car 13                   |
| 2 Type2Car 14                   |
| 3 Type3Car NULL                 |
| 3 Type3Car NULL                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

If I don't have this line if the user 13 didn't specify any cars for this type it won't display since user 14 has chosen one

Comment: Does the JSON somehow represent sample data of what is currently in your tables? Can you post a more easy-to-interpret version (flat text)

Comment: I've updated with ASCII output about what is going on and what expected. It's pretty hard to explain, apologies if you don't understand, I'm trying to be as clear as possible but that's not easy

Comment: Why are you not complaining that type2car also has no null row?

Comment: I forgot to add it but that is the same for others in fact. I'm editing. Someone answered with an answer that was working very close from what I need but he unfortunaterly deleted it

Comment: So you basically always want a null row for each car as well as non null rows showing cars that are booked?

Comment: That's right. I'm adding the answer given that was close to what I want

Comment: I'd do that with a union plus an inner join; select the cars plus nulls, union the cars inner join the users

Comment: (It's actually easier to do the other way round, whatever the laravel/eloquent way of writing `select cars.id, users.id from cars inner join users on cars.whatever = users.whatever UNION ALL select cars.id,null FROM cars` - I didn't select all of the columns you wanted but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for help. Solved my problem with eloquent but I also looked for what you said to learn more things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on deleted answer, I solved my issue :

```
return TypeCars::with('cars')->leftJoin('user_cars', function($join){
    $join->on('user_cars.id', '=', 'type_cars.id');
        $join->on('user_cars.id', '=', DB::raw(1)); 
})
    ->whereNull('user_cars.id')
    ->where('user_cars.id', '=', 1)
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```

`DB::raw` is needed to avoid Eloquent from quoting raw values.